# generate nested lines inside control code in Silm template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the slim code to be nested inside the code generated in control code.

Giving an example, I want this slim code

```
- if !!defined?(outside_form)
  = outside_form.fields_for 'fields[]', @obj do |inside_form|
- else
  = fields_for 'fields[]', @obj do |inside_form|

= inside_form.text_field :attr
```

to be equivalent to this erb code

```
<% if !!defined?(outside_form) %>
  <%= outside_form.fields_for 'fields[]', @obj do |inside_form| %>
<% else %>
  <%= fields_for 'fields[]', @obj do |inside_form| %>
<% end %>

   <%= inside_form.text_field :attr %>
  <% end %>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your purpose? can you explain it in little bit? You want to convert single file or whole application??

Comment: This slim code is a rails partial file, and want the generated html (namely, the name attribute on text field) to be different depending on if outside_form exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You have syntax error in your code. You can't close your else block like this, you'll have to write fields inside blocks only. It's like you open a child block inside a parent block and then want to close your child block after parents, which is wrong.  **What you can do is instead use a partial***

```
- if !!defined?(outside_form)
  = outside_form.fields_for 'fields[]', @obj do |inside_form|
    = render partial: "fields", locals: {inside_form: inside_form}
- else
  = fields_for 'fields[]', @obj do |inside_form|
    = render partial: "fields", locals: {inside_form: inside_form}

#_fields.html.slim
= inside_form.text_field :attr
## other form fields here
```